# Visual Studio installation stops working after splash screen appears

Tags: visual-studio

I'm on windows 7 64 bit and every time I run `vs_Community.exe` after downloading it, it stops working and the problem details show this:

```
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe
  Application Version:  2.7.3132.26759
  Application Timestamp:    9b581caf
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.17514
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4ce7c78c
  Exception Code:   c06d007e
  Exception Offset: 000000000000a49d
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: 7283
  Additional Information 2: 72836eb6216b49be15302fdb224c1b5d
  Additional Information 3: 3a01
  Additional Information 4: 3a018db631e662ba3d328203cc490b3a
```

It worked on windows 7 32 bit just fine so it can't be the fact that I'm on windows 7.

Comment: Caused by a missing DLL, no it doesn't tell you which one.  Probably an important one that's part of the operating system.  SysInternals' ProcMon ought to show it searching for that DLL and not finding it.

Comment: @HansPassant could you help me out with this? i'm not exactly experienced with procmon

Comment: Well, you have *the* ideal reason to spend the time to get experienced with that tool.   It is quite useful.  Ask questions about it at superuser.com.